# JavaScript count items that have been run in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to Javascript so i'm looking for a bit of help. 
I have a webpage that loads a iframe and loops through loads of URLs. This all works after a bit of help.

However i now need a div showing the count of the completed urls, so everytime it does one it increases the count by one.

Any ideads?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var urls1 =
  [
    #myList1#
  ];

function showUrl1(idx)
{
  var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
  f1.onload = function()
  {
    var next = idx === urls1.length? null: ++idx;
  setTimeout(function()
  {   
      if(next != null)
        {
       showUrl1(next);
     }

  }, 500);
 }
 f1.src = urls1[idx];
}

function start()
{
  showUrl1(0);
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
  <div class="container">
    <iframe class="show1" id="f1" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    <div class="count1"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to actually do this? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Where are you putting this count to the page?

Comment: sorry i missed that bit off, I wanted it in the div, count1

Comment: You can use the `setTimeout` with zero value or better use `requestAnimationFrame` Method. I don't why you are using setTimeout with a value of 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the div's `.innerHTML` = the value of your index.

```js
var urls1 = [
  'https://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t1.cfm',
  'https://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t2.cfm',
  'https://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t3.cfm',
  'https://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t4.cfm',
  'https://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t5.cfm'
];

function showUrl1(idx) {
  var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
  f1.onload = function() {
    if (idx >= urls1.length) {
      return;
    }

    var next = ++idx;
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (next != null) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = idx;
        showUrl1(next);
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  f1.src = urls1[idx];
}

function start() {
  showUrl1(0);
}

start();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe class="show1" id="f1" src="about:blank"></iframe>
  <div id="counter" class="count1">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, I knew it wasn't hard to do my limited knowledge of Javascript i couldn't work it out. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem! Just don't forget to mark it as answer _if_ you use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div with id `count1` that has the number 0. Target the div using `document.getElementById('count1')` as you're already doing. Right below your `if` statement, target that element and set its innerHTML equal to `idx`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` to your `div` with `class='count1'` and set it's value equal to the index.

```
<script>

    var i = 0;

    $document.getElementByID('count1').innerHTML = "URL Count: "+'index here';



</script>
```